# Angular 6 Form Creation

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-forms

I am creating a form using Angular 6 but in my form I have 50 or more fields than in 'ts' file do I have to declare all the fields, something, for example, I am using reactive forms than

```
userCreation = new FormGroup({
  firstName: new FormControl(''),
  lastName: new FormControl(''),
  ........
  so on
});
```

and if I am using template driven than also for ngModel do I have to define all files in the object

```
userCreation: {
  firstName: any;
  lastName: any;
  ...........
  so on
};
```

is there anyway so I can prevent this declaration or I have to follow it, it is mandatory?

Comment: No, you don't really have to. You are eventually going to get a structure when you get the `value` from this form. So why bother.

Comment: it gives me error like this :Cannot read property 'id' of undefined and if i use reactive forms it show error Cannot find control with name:id

Comment: if you need to validate them using reactive form method then you need to define them.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare your object in a different file, like:

`Person.ts`:

```
export class Person {
    firstname: string;
    lastName: string;
    ...
}
```

Your main `.ts` file:

```
let fg = this.formBuilder.group(
    new Person()
)
```

Comment: here also i have to define that 50 or more fields ? so it will be almost same

Comment: You cannot do it like this if you want to pass validators for any of the properties. The class properties need to be of type (string | ((control: AbstractControl) => ValidationErrors))[] if you want to pass in validators. Also, you need to create a constructor, so you end up with much more code.

Comment: @user3458271 At least you only have to define them once. I dunno how you would define 50 fields without telling the code what they are.

@EliasGarcia You can add them later using `fg.get('firstname').setValidators(...)`, but yes this is also true.

Answer (score 0):

Angular reactive form style required to setup the formGroup and map these control name with formControlName to the html element otherwise you will got an error

```
related Error: Cannot find control with name: '....'
```

setup 50 form control can be hard so because you need to setup formGroup and init and create the html template for the formgroup so for the case you can create form dynamic read this ([Demystifying dynamic Forms in Angular](https://juristr.com/blog/2017/10/demystify-dynamic-angular-forms/)) or you can use [ngx-formly](https://github.com/formly-js/ngx-formly)

Angular template from can be another option that can be setup eraser than 
reactive form (but still I recommand useing reactive form for complex form )
[read this](https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-forms-template-driven)

[**stackblitz demo - template from**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-template-form-example)